Automatically change text/date in Word document and send it every year
I would like to get the following thing done:
I have got an Microsoft Word Document with on top a date like June 13th 2024.
And I would like to send this document every year automatically and also before sending it, it first needs to change the date in on the document of the day sending it.
Is there a script or something to get this done? I know there are things you can do in Excel but itś different with Word.
Hope someone can point me to the right direction.
Thank you!
I tried finding a script online but I just cannot find it.

on top Do you mean it is on doc. header? If the action is performed annually, I don't think it necessarily requires automation through a script.

Hi, this is a programming forum, not a Word forum. Your question is off-topic here and likely will be closed without answers. The confusion is understandable. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  This would be an appropriate question on the Microsoft Community https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word   This can be done with one of the Date fields in Word fairly easily, not even requiring a macro. See my page https://addbalance.com/word/datefields1.htm#PageStart.
